# Is a "Day" table a good idea in this case?

Tags: sql

So, a friend and I are designing a *Workout Tracker* application as a side project. In this application, you can have `Programs` which include a group of `Workouts` which have a bunch of `Sets`. Let's suppose that you only train once per day and not always do you want to train a specific `Workout`, instead, you'd want to add the exercises while training.
So, we have thought of creating a table named `Day` which would have the following attributes:

- ID - as primary key (probably the date)
- WorkoutID - Nullable, if the date does not have any workout.

Also, there would be an auxiliar table named `DayExercices` which would hold all the exercises done in that day.

These scheme would allow us to link a `Workout` (which would bring us to it's exercises in the table `WorkoutExercices`) and, if the user would want to add any other exercise on that day it would be possible since it would be added to the `DayExercices`.

However, would this be considered good practice? Should we change the database scheme?

This is the current database scheme.

[image: CurrentDatabaseScheme]

Comment: BTW, it's "exercise" not "exercice".

Comment: General comments: RPE isn't really applicable to time or cardio type sets so maybe move that into the RepSet table. I think it would be helpful to have a datetime in the RepSet table so, if you are good about hitting the "add set" button then you are able to keep track of rest too. WorkoutMuscles seems like a view, not a table.

Comment: @Brad That's true, good point.

Comment: The superfluous `WorkoutMuscles` was the first that I noticed, too. Then, I don't understand the sets. One exercise contains multiple sets and each set contains multiple rep sets and/or multiple time sets and/or multiple cardio sets? And then I don't see what is the *plan* ("in workout xy you must do exercise yz in three sets of 12-15, 12-15, 10-12 repetitions") and what is the actual *completed* training ("on Feb 3, 2020 I did workout xy and exercise yz in three sets of 15 (50kg), 13 (50kg), and 10 (45kg) repetitions"). But maybe I just know too little about such workouts/programs.

Comment: As to a pre-planned workout vs. an ad-hoc training: well, that's an ad-hoc workout then. You could probably just use the same tables. Maybe give the workout table a flag whether it's planned (and hence in the list of daily workout suggestions) or ad-hoc (done once and not in the list of daily workout suggestions).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So whenever an exercise is added ad-hoc it would be added to a `Workout` which would be flagged as `ad-hoc`, for instance?

Comment: Yes, that's about the idea. If I don't choose a particular workout, but just do some exercises, an ad-hoc workout gets created for these. Don't know if this would work for you, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

So basically from what I've understood is that an exercise can indeed happen more than once a day so you would need something like this:

ID, Day, ExerciseID

The Id will be the primary key cause you can have multiple same pairs of Day, ExerciseID.

Also I took a quick look to your schema and it seems to me like you have a circle there. I would suggest throwing away the table `WorkoutMuscles`. A workout is a set of exercises and those exercises actually train your muscles. For example imagine that you add a new exercise under a workout, this means that you would need to also update the `WorkoutMuscles`. Furthermore I suggest renaming the `WorkoutExercises` table to `Exercises`. The tables should be named us their entities not the relation they have.

You can create views if you want to retrieve the information more easily.

Comment: Allright, thanks for your reply, I will give it a try! Well, `MuscleGroups` would work like tags. Probably giving tags only to the exercises is enough!